# What does docker's -j$(nproc) mean?

Tags: php, docker

In the docker template file, some commands must be followed by -j$(nproc). What does it mean?

For example: when php installs gd library: docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no "must" about `-j`, it's optional to spawn `nproc` [which is a command to return the number of processors] parallel build jobs to compile the extensions. It is simply passed through to `make`'s `-j` option:

> ```
>    -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
>         Specifies the number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one -j option,
>         the  last  one is effective.  If the -j option is given without an argument, make will not limit the
>         number of jobs that can run simultaneously.
> ```

Really docker-php-ext-install is just a bit of bash handwaving around make: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-install

**TLDR:** `-j$(nproc)` make build go fast.